# How would relativistic length contraction appear if a slow motion video were taken of a rapidly accelerating uncompressible object?

Tags: special-relativity

A rod is at rest relative to an observer. 
The observer is 'ahead' of the rod by some distance, on a straight road and on the opposite side of the road to the rod. The observer is looking back at the rod on the opposite side.

The rod suddenly accelerates to relativistic speeds towards the observer with a known and precise acceleration of A. It manages to achieve these speeds before passing the observer and continues to accelerate - in the field of view of the observer in other words.

The rod is perfectly uncompressible and undergoes no subjective change of length as a result of the thrust. It is a hypothetical object that undergoes simultaneous acceleration along its length. (Edit: this is just to remove the complexities of mechanical compression from the question)

The observer has a slow motion video camera and is recording the process.

Given that the rod has a known starting position and precise known acceleration, there is a known expected pathway the rod should be taking. That path of positions can be represented as a plot of x (relative to observer) against time.

The observer plays back the slow motion video and attempts to note on the graph the change in apparent length of the rod, around the expected positions of the front and rear of the rod.

With all of that, the questions are:

Around what point on the rod does the compression appear to take place? Does it appear to begin to shrink from the front, from the rear, around the center, or somewhere else? Is the answer dependent on if the rod is moving towards the observer or away from the observer?

Comment: The problem with an incompressible rod is that it's not clear how such a rod holds together without its intermolecular forces travelling faster than the speed of light. But assuming an incompressible rod, it would compress from the point nearest to the observer first. So if it took a jolt towards you (and then returned to being stationary without passing you),  then it would progressively scan from its front into a contracted object, and then as it accelerated back to stationary, it would scan from its front into a normal length...

Comment: ...I use the word "scan" because remember you have to wait for a whole wavelength to be received each time you sample any part of its overall appearance, and these are emitted from different relative distances from you.

Comment: So what you'd see initially is part of the object cascading towards you in a compressed form, whilst it's tail end remained stationary, and at the interface between the two parts you'd receive a completely distorted and irregular wave pattern as the electric field transitioned into a magnetic field (and I'm not even sure how an observer would perceive this - quite possibly it would just appear as a gap or a smear between the two halves).

Comment: Cool! Sounds like the beginnings of a new sci-fi Netflix original!

Comment: Except it's not sci-fi, it's just a complex and dynamic case of describing the behaviour of classical waves. And all the visual effects were probably in the opening credits of Star Trek TNG 30 years ago haha!